# Display corresponding date of first cell that contains a number per person

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am working in Excel with 2 spreadsheets such as the following:

Sheet 1: 'Summary'

> | -- | ---A -----| ------ B -----|--C--  |--  D - |--  E--  |--  F--  |-  G-  |
>   | 1 |__   ID___   | Start Date | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN |
>
> | 2 | Y01A01 |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***|_1_ *|*_   1 ***_*_**|  _ 1_ |_   1__ |  1_  |
>   | 3 | Y01A02 |***_*__*_*__*_*___**|_0_ |_   0__ |_   0__ |_   1__ |  1  |
>
> | 4 | Y01A03 |***_*__*_*__*_*___**|_   1_ |_   1_ | _  1_ |__   1_ |_  0  |

Sheet 2: 'Feb'

> | --  |  ----  A -  |  ----   B  -----    | -- C  - |--  D -- | ----- E  --------       |
>   | 1 |   ID_***_*__**   |    Date____    | Fever|Cough|Running Nose|
>
> | 2 | Y01A01 | 1/2/2013   |   NA __ |  NA_**_ |   NA      *_*__*_*___** |
>
> | 3 | Y01A01 | 2/2/2013   |   NA__ |  NA **__ |   NA      *_*__*_*___** |
>
> | 4 | Y01A01 | 3/2/2013   |   0 ***_*__** |_   1 __ | _  1_***_*__*_*____**|

Sheet 1 is a summary table of every participants of a flu prevention program. They would have to record their flu symptom everyday month by month. Under the column of C:G (i.e. Feb to June), "1" indicates yes the person has done so and "0" indicates no. However, not every person participate to the program and starts recording on the first day of a month. For instance on Sheet 2, participant Y01A01 started on 3/2/2013 and thus no records were shown (i.e. NA) on 1/2/2013 and 2/2/2013. (on Sheet 2, 0 = no; 1 = yes)

My question is that I would like to find the start date (Sheet 1, Column B) for every person using Excel formula.

I have tried to use the formula

```
=INDEX('Feb'!B:B,MATCH(Summary!A2,'Feb'!A:A,0),ISNUMBER(INDEX('Feb'!C:C,MATCH(Summary!A2,'Feb'!A:A,0))))
```

But it shows 1/2/2013 incorrectly, instead of 3/2/2013.

Comment: Try `VLOOKUP()` formula

Comment: Do you consider using VBA?

Comment: It is a question wheter you want to use it or not. If yes I will provide you code. Some people want to use formula at all cost.

Comment: Sure! I would like to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you know how to handle macros? If you don't please comment I will guide you.

```
Sub first_date()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange1 As Range


Worksheets("Summary").Select

Set MyRange = Worksheets("Summary").Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Worksheets("Feb").Select

Set MyRange1 = Worksheets("Feb").Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Worksheets("Summary").Select

For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
    With MyRange1
    Set rng1 = .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

            Do

                If IsNumeric(rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value) Then

                MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

                Exit Do:

                End If

            Set rng1 = .Cells.FindNext(rng1)

            Loop While rng1.Address <> strAddress

        End If

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to get the corresponding start date for each ID(from sheet 2 to sheet 1) you can use `=VLOOKUP($A2,FEB!$A$2:$B$65536,2,0)`

Comment: However I am not only looking up for the date the ID first appears, but such with the first 0 or 1 appears on sheet 2 'C2:E4', or simply just column 'C'